# How to let terminal window be closed automatically in a linux Console Application when run by IDE

Tags: c++, linux, ide, terminal, console-application

When I compile a C++ console application in a Linux IDE like Qt Creator or code::blocks, the terminal window (unlike Windows Console) waits for pressing Enter to be closed. Codes like `exit(0)` and `system("exit")` don't work.

Is there any code or option in Qt IDE to let the terminal window (xterm or konsole) be closed automatically after execution.

Comment: A console application is supposed to be run from inside an existing terminal..... However, you could use `xterm -e yourapplication` to run it in a new terminal which would disappear when the application terminates.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually made for you. If you build executable of your application and run it from terminal (outside of IDE), it (your application... not the terminal) will close after execution (return in main).

CodeBlocks uses smth called cb_console_runner to run executables and wait for ENTER to close terminal. I am not sure how is it possible to make it work without cb_console_runner

EDIT: In codeBlocks... remove/rename cb_console_runner in /bin and it is solved:)
to make it easier: run this command:

```
sudo mv /bin/cb_console_runner cb_console_runner_s
```

Comment: I'm looking for an option in IDE. It's annoying if you need to compile many times.

Comment: You don't need an IDE to build or to run your program.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus you should probably update the title to mention ide

Answer (score 1):

In QtCreator in Project->Run settings
uncheck "Run in Terminal"